# how can I read my id row from datatables jquery in php / codeigniter?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, datatables

I want to get the row id to after sent it to php code,but im using datatables jquery plugin , however I show my id into datables , but datatables is generating td instead of inputs. if it were it will be easy to read it in php, but how can I read my row id of datable in php... I tried $_POST, but I cant because I havent any name on tds. other thing im using codeigniter. once I can read my id row I can use it for where id = id to update my item.

table

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "lengthChange": false,
        responsive: true,
        dom: 'Blfrtip',
        buttons: [{
             extend: 'excelHtml5',
             exportOptions:{
                columns: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
             }
        },{
            extend: 'csvHtml5',
            exportOptions:{
                columns: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
            }
        },{
            extend: 'pdf',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
            }
        }],
        ajax: {
            url: URL_GET_DATATABLE,
            type: 'POST',
        },
        columnDefs:[{
            targets: -1,
            data: null,
            defaultContent: "<a href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>"

        },{
            targets: 6,
            render: function (data) {
                return (data == 1) ? "<span class='label label-success'>active</span>":"<span class='label label-danger'>inactive</span>";
            }
        }],
        fnRowCallback: function (data,nRow) {
            if (nRow[6] == 0) {
                $(data).css({'background-color':'#f2dede'});
            }else if(nRow[6] == 1){
                $(data).css({'background-color':'#dff0d8'});
            }else{

            }
        }
    });
```

model

```
public function datatable(){
        $this->db->select('id,descripcion,precio_compra,precio_venta,precio_mayoreo,existencia_minima,existencia,storelte_articulos.status');
        $this->db->from('storelte_articulos');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

controller

```
public function datatable(){
        $array = $this->products->datatable();
        $this->json($array);
        $data = array();
        foreach ($array as $rows){
            array_push($data, array(
                $rows['id'],
                $rows['descripcion'],
                $rows['precio_compra'],
                $rows['precio_venta'],
                $rows['precio_mayoreo'],    
                $rows['existencia'],
                $rows['status']
            ));
        }
        $this->json(array('data' => $data));
    }
```

update controller

```
public function updateProduct($data){
        $this->db->update('storelte_articulos',$data);
        $this->db->where('id');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your ID into an input, but set it as hidden. That way the data isn't being shown to the end user, but it is available through post data.

As it is able to be seen with developer tools / inspect I would suggest encoding it for display then decoding it for use with the database queries.